# Is it possible to load partial object schemes from an existing database using .Net EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a DB table created with .net ef with the following scheme:

Task(id, title, description, status)

I currently have a server that fully uses this scheme and has a class that represents this object

```
public class Task {

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

}
```

I now want to set up another separate statistics server on another project that only need Id and Status (**read only**)

```
public class Task {

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

}
```

Is it possible to link a context with this object which is does not represent the full scheme to my existing DB table using .net ef core?

Edit:
I have added an image to represent the required situation better
[image]

Comment: Yes you can (if the fileds allow nulls)

Comment: could you pass in the sql manually? Something like "Select Id, Status FROM [schema].Task"?

Comment: The image doesn't help. The question isn't clear either. A DbContext or DbSet aren't databases and tables they are the way that *entities* get mapped to tables. Can you map to different tables? Yes, if you ensure you never try to load non-existent properties. Should you do so? No, because the other database contains *statistics* not *definitions* of tasks. Those are different things/entities.

Comment: Creating another entity costs nothing. Just create a TaskStatistics entity for the other database. You probably need a different context too because reporting databases have very different schemas from OLTP databases. The new context will probably be a lot simpler and easier to use than trying to repurpose a model made for a different schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand you then you have one database and two projects which work with this database. The first project handles tasks and the second project get statistics about tasks. In this case it is better to combine two projects into a solution. In the solution your should extract class library with your entities (domain models). As example of your entities:

```
public class Task {

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

}
```

Also you should extract access layer (dbContext, dbSet, repositories etc.) into separate class library.

Both projects should use this two libraries. Each project should have own set of view classes. As example of view class is:

```
public class Task {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

}
```

Your can map domain model (entity) to view model yourself or use something like Automapper (the second case is better).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view in SQL server that represents exactly those two fields from your task table and map it to your statistics table.